# How to fetch medicare insurance records using sodapy

Tags: python, socrata, soda

How I can get medicare records using sodapy (https://github.com/xmunoz/sodapy#client).

I want to verify the patient's eligibility for insurance. 
It's just to ensure whether he/she has already claimed the insured products or not and also to validate the insurance using medicare ID.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.socrata.com/search.html?q=medicare

No result is shown.

This questions need more context.

Comment: I found these API from medicare website, but I don't  how to hit the exact url with which parameter to get the concise information.
Here's the website URL:
https://data.medicare.gov/developers